# Use of "as good" and "as well"

Tags: american-english, british-english, australian-english, canadian-english

Are these two sentences correct?

1. This is as good as ...
2. This works as well as ...

Edit:

1. This one is as good as the other one.
2. This one works as well as the other one.

Comment: Since your examples are all correct, what did your own dictionaries, phrase-books or search engines leave unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edits are correct.

*Good* is an adjective and describes nouns,  in this case the subject of the sentence (*this*).

*Well* is an adverb and modifies verbs, in this case *works*.

Answer (score 0):

"As good as" an adjective that is used for equality. "As well as" an adverb that is used for equality.

Comment: Grammatically adjective modify noun ,and adverb modify verb.

Answer (score -3):

"This is as good as..." is *right*. "This works as well as..." can have 1000 substitutes and it's *not right*.

Comment: Please see my edit.